# Ansible: Removing empty values from a list and assigning it to a new list

Tags: ansible

I have a list generated in ansible using values gathered by a task. In that list, there are empty strings as some of the keys don't have values assigned to them. So, what I am trying to achieve is to assign that list to a new list but without those empty values.

```
list1: [
   "a",
   "b",
   "",
   "7",
   ""
]
```

I have tried the following and it doesn't seem to work:

```
set_fact:
  list2: "{{ list1 1 | rejectattr('') |list }}"
```

Is anyone able to point me what I am doing wrong and provide a solution to my issue?

`Ansible version: 2.9.1`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Q: ***Remove empty values from list1 ["a", "b", "", "7", ""]***

A: Use the filter [*select*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.select). Quoting:

> *"If no test is specified, each object will be evaluated as a boolean."*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list2: "{{ list1|select() }}"
      vars:
        list1: ["a", "b", "", "7", ""]
```

gives

```yaml
    list2: [a, b, '7']
```

Q: ***If an element is 0 or False ?***

A: Both *0* and *False* evaluate to boolean *False*. The filter *select* will remove them too

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list2: "{{ list1|select() }}"
      vars:
        list1: ["a", "b", 0, "7", False, ""]
```

gives the same result

```yaml
    list2: [a, b, '7']
```

To [*reject*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.reject) empty strings only use the test [*match*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings)

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list2: "{{ list1|reject('match', '^$') }}"
      vars:
        list1: ["a", "b", 0, "7", False, ""]
```

gives

```yaml
    list2: [a, b, 0, '7', false]
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked perfectly well! Would you also able to tell me how can I exclude a certain item in list 1 (based on string match) to copy to list 2? For eg. list1 = ["a", "b,"7", " ", "g", "a"] and list2 gets ["b", "7", "g"] ?

Comment: To exclude certain items try a combination of [list filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#list-filters). Probably `unique, difference` in particular.

Comment: and if an element is 0 or False ?

Comment: Then use the explicit match and regex.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below

```
  vars:
   list1: [ "a", "b", "", "7", "" ]
   list2:  []

  tasks:
  - name: test
    set_fact:
     list2: "{{list2  + [item]}}"
    when: item != ""
    with_items:
     - "{{list1}}"
```

Output

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "7"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This gave me the result: '"list2": "[AnsibleUndefined]"'

Comment: did you define the  list2:  [] in the vars as above

Comment: Yes, I did initialize an empty list, but I did it as a set_fact rather than vars